# HTML Form: Can submitted GET/POST parameters be suppressed using only HTML or CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am volunteering on a website-based project that is trying to make all pages fully operable JavaScript free before adding any JavaScript for enhancements, and I was asked to investigate whether or not a particular scenario could be handled purely through HTML/CSS.

What we have is a form that is populated to help us filter a list of tickets that are displayed on the screen after a page update through a GET action, which itself works fine, but the concern with the current implementation is that the URL cannot be made into a permanent link.  The request, however, to keep the permanent link as minimal as possible, is to only send GET parameters for fields that are populated with something (so, suppressing GET parameters for fields that are blank) instead of having a different GET parameter for each form field on the page.

I have thought of several ways that could be done, most including JavaScript (example: create fields with ids but no names and a hidden field w/ name that uses JS to grab the data from the fields), but also one that would be a POST action with a redirect back to the GET with a human readable string that could be permanently used.  The lead dev, however would prefer not to go through the POST/redirect method if at all possible.

That being said, I'm trying to make sure I cover all my bases and ask experts their thoughts on this before I strongly push for the POST/redirect solution:  Is there a way using only HTML & CSS to directly suppress GET parameters of a form for fields that are blank without using a POST/redirect?

Comment: Basically, you just wanna nix values that aren't the default? You could toss a submit-preprocessing into it via Javascript that marks any non-dirty field as disabled before submitting.

Comment: Curious as to why you do not want javascript? Is this an internal or external use site?

Comment: Bindrid: The site is an open source project for other free/libre/open projects, and there are a lot of people we've been talking to that are opposed to JS and have a lot of JS blockers, so we're trying to cater to the potential user population.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, suppressing fields from being submitted in an HTML form with method of "GET" is not possible without using JavaScript, or instead submitting the form with a POST method and using a server side function to minimize the form.

What fields are submitted are defined by the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) and HTML and CSS alone cannot modify this behavior and still have the browser be compliant with the standards.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot programmatically suppress any default browser behavior without using some kind of client scripting language, like JavaScript.

As a side note, you say "JavaScript for enhancements", but JavaScript is not used for enhancements these days. And no one in the real world would except a decent front-end without the use of JavaScript. I would suggest you simply use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can avoid Javascript here to pre process before submission to eliminate unchanged /empty form fields.